# Is it possible to create a calendar event for a whole team using the graph api

Tags: calendar, microsoft-graph-api, microsoft-teams, azure-ad-graph-api, microsoft-graph-teams

I'm trying to create a calendar event using the graph api that behaves in the same manner that manually creating an event in a channel using the Microsoft Team client would. In other words an event that shows up in the chat and "belongs"  to the team. I want the event to behave as seen [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/r8Fel.png).

So far i've tried to use the following endpoints with no luck. On all endpoints i've tried adding the team itself as a recipient/participant of the event but it had no result.

```
POST /groups/{id}/events
POST /groups/{id}/calendar/events
POST /users/{id | userPrincipalName}/events
```

Any help is appreciated at this stage.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Teams in O365 portal will call an internal Teams API to finish the things you mentioned as your screenshot shows.

It doesn't call Microsoft Graph API. In another words, MS Graph doesn't provide an endpoint which schedules an online meeting in a channel currently.

[Create an event as an online meeting](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/calendar-post-events?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http#example-2-create-and-enable-an-event-as-an-online-meeting) doesn't send meeting info into a channel. Neither does [Create onlineMeeting](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/application-post-onlinemeetings?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http).

There is a workaround for you: [create a Online meeting](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/application-post-onlinemeetings?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http) and then [post information about that to a channel](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/channel-post-messages?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http).

A related [article](https://myteamsday.com/2019/09/10/using-graph-api-to-create-a-instant-meeting-in-teams/) for your reference.